# How to send database table name like a parameter in the request and handle it in the function on server?

Tags: rest, api, slim

I have my own API and everything is just fine, but I need help with this : 
I wabt a function to get database table name within its parameters and according to that name it will insert the data.
For example :

```
function InsertData( $Employee,$userId,...) {
$query = INSERT INTO $Employee(...,...,...,...) VALUES (?,?,?,...)
}


function InsertData( $Passenger,$userId,...) {
$query = INSERT INTO $Passenger(...,...,...,...) VALUES (?,?,?,...)
}
```

```
public function createPost ($tablename,$userid,$content){

    $postStatement = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO '.$tablename.'(userid,content) VALUES (?,?)");
    $postStatement ->bind_param("is",$userid,$content);
    if ($postStatement ->execute()){
        return DONE;
    }else{
        return NOT_DONE;
}
```

It always show me message : Internal Server Error

Comment: The bind_param call looks suspicious to me. Also the tablename should be quoted for security reasons. Try to enable the PDO Error mode: `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,`. [*](https://odan.github.io/2017/01/07/basic-crud-operations-with-pdo.html)

Comment: @odan nothing happend
What do you mean about #quoted ? do you mean that i should quote every name? is that more professional?
and what about the question?, do you have any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would try to create a custom method for every query.

1. Make sure that PDO throws exceptions:

```php
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';
$collate = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES $charset COLLATE $collate"
];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Then create a method for each query. Example:

```php
public function insertPassenger(string $firstName, string $lastName): int
    $row = [
        'first_name' => $firstName,
        'last_name' => $lastName,
    ];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO passengers SET first_name=:first_name, last_name=:last_name;";
    $this->pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($row);

    return (int)$this->pdo->lastInsertId();
}

public function insertReservation(int flightId, $passengerId): int
    $row = [
        'flight_id' => $flightId,
        'passenger_id' => $passengerId,
    ];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO reservations SET flight_id=:flight_id, passenger_id=:passenger_id;";
    $this->pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($row);

    return (int)$this->pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```